# Trouble running command on Terminator launch

Tags: command-line, bash, terminator

According to the Terminator man page, I can use the `--command` flag when running the `terminator` command to run a command when the terminal window opens. However, I can't seem to get it working. I've tried the following:

```
terminator --command="ls"
terminator --command ls
terminator --command "ls"
```

The first step is to get this working. Secondly, the man page also points out that it will run the command "instead of your default shell or profile specified command." Does that mean aliases from my `.bashrc` file won't be loaded in? If so, how can I have them load in?

The full command I'm going for is something like this:

```
terminator --command ssh-apixel --geometry 900x575+110+55 --new-tab
```

where `ssh-apixel` is an alias defined in my `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Before asking this question, did you test it works with another command, e.g. "top"

Comment: @vanadium Yes, I've tried it with multiple commands

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me in the end:

```
terminator -e "bash --rcfile <(echo '. /home/apixel/.bashrc; ssh user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx')" --geometry 900x575+110+55 --new-tab
```